# MFC(unicode): how do i convert a wstring filepath to a string path?

Tags: c++, mfc, wstring

I have a application created with MFC, C++, and uses Unicode.

I have to load a texture with a wstring file path. This wstring file path is given by the system and I don't need to display it anywhere. I just need to pass it to a texture loading method. Unfortunately, the texture loading method(from a lib) only take a string filePath. Something like below:

```
wstring wstringPath = L"abc路徑";// how do I convert it to a string path to used in the following method
stbi_load(stringPath, &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0); //texture loading method
```

I have searched a lot and didn't found a good answer(or too complex) to solve the issue. Anyone can help?

Something I have tried and not working:

```
size_t len = wcslen(wstringPath .c_str()) + 1;

size_t newLen = len * 2;
char* newPath = new char[newLen];

wcstombs(newPath, wstringPath .c_str(), sizeof(newPath));

glGenTextures(1, &m_textureID);

int width, height, nrComponents;
unsigned char *data = stbi_load(newPath, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
```

Comment: `std::string` accepts all utf8 or Chinese/Japanese characters.

Comment: In MFC/ATL use `std::string utf8(CW2A(L"abc路徑", CP_UTF8))` then send `utf8.c_str()`, or use `WideCharToMultiByte` with `CP_UTF8` flag.

Comment: What character encoding does `stbi_load` expect?

Comment: According to this page https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_write.h you have to add `#define STBIW_WINDOWS_UTF8` and send UTF8, the library will probably can convert back to UTF16 and use the right APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the API `stbi_load` and it seems to take a `const char*` for the filename.

In that case, the laziest and best way is to use the `CString` classes.

```
#include <atlstr.h> // might not need if you already have MFC stuff included

CStringA filePathA(wstringPath.c_str()); // it converts using CP_THREAD_ACP

stbi_load(filePathA, ....); // automatically casts to LPCSTR (const char*)
```

=================================================

Since there is new information that you need to use UTF-8 to call those APIS, probably need a function like this:

```
CStringA GetUtf8String(LPCWSTR lpwz)
{
    CStringA strRet;

    if (lpwz == nullptr || (*lpwz == 0))
        return strRet;

    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, lpwz, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, lpwz, -1, strRet.GetBufferSetLength(len), len, NULL, NULL);

    strRet.ReleaseBuffer();

    return strRet;
}
```

Then you'd call it like:

```
wstring wstringPath = L"abc路徑";
stbi_load(GetUtf8String(wstringPath.c_str()), blah, blah, blah);
```

Comment: OP mentioned `L"abc路徑"`, I doubt this fits in any ANSI string. It needs UTF8, or maybe it can't handle that, it should be short filename. Same problem with the other answer.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani It probably works on a machine with the Chinese charset. On those machines, the "ANSI" charset is really a DBCS char set. It can handle English and Chinese just fine. For English characters, they all have to fit in the character values < 127. I worked on a non-Unicode, non-UTF8 Windows MFC program that was translated to Japanese. Seemed to work find. I guess they'll let us know if it doesn't.

Comment: Then `wcstombs` should do the same thing, although OP's usage is wrong. I never understood DBCS, I have to take your word for it.

Comment: Sorry, this solution doesn't work for me.  When I try to open a filename  containing Chinese characters, it failed. My win10 setting is: "English(United States)" as windows display language; "English(Canada)" as Regional format; preferred languages are "English(Canada)", "English(United States)" and "Chinese(simplified, China". I can switch between the preferred languages for typing input.

Comment: What is the ANSI code page of the system? i.e. if you go to Region Settings and go to the Administrative page, what is the "Current language for non-Unicode programs"?

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson My "Current language for non-Unicode programs" is "English(United States)".

Comment: Well, that's interesting... I'd look for a Unicode API or maybe try changing the language for non-Unicode programs to the flavor of Chinese you want to use.

Comment: That's not feasible. You'd have to know ahead of time which code page can represent all characters in the input file name, temporarily change the calling thread's code page, and then reset it when the function call returns. All bets are off in case the file name cannot be represented with any single code page. The correct solution is to convert to UTF-8 which the stb\* library [apparently supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69843859/mfcunicode-how-do-i-convert-a-wstring-filepath-to-a-string-path#comment123466415_69843859).

Comment: There's `stbiw_convert_wchar_to_utf8` already if you `#define STBIW_WINDOWS_UTF8`, so you don't need to roll your own.

Answer (score -1):

You can use (for MS Windows only) the function `WideCharToMultiByte`. Codepage for target you can set as `CP_ACP`.